# How to retrieve a value on prompt?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript, I have to use a `prompt` and enter a `value`.

[image]

I have to retrieve this value on a field but I don't get this value. My code is incomplete.

[image]

My HTML

```
<body>
  <h1>Exercise 8</h1>
   <label>Hours : <input type="text" id='h' /></label>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

My JS

```
var hours = parseInt(prompt('Enter your hours please : '));

objet.addEventListener('load', main);


function main(){

    hours = document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
    alert(hours);
}
```

```js
var hours = parseInt(prompt('Enter your hours please : '));

objet.addEventListener('load', main);


function main(){

 hours = document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
 alert(hours);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="Thing.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>

 <body>
  <h1>Exercise 8</h1>
   <label>Hours : <input type="text" id='h' /></label>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Thank you...

Comment: What is this block of code`objet.addEventListener('load', main);`?

Comment: `objet.addEventListener('load', main);` is not doing anything, so take that out. Also, `main()` is declared but not called. If you want to run main use the command: `main();`

Comment: @eyl327: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the value entered by the user and insert into the input element.

```js
var hours = parseInt(prompt('Enter your hours please : '));

if (hours != null) {
  document.getElementById("h").value = hours
  alert(hours)
}
```

```html
<h1>Exercise 8</h1>
<label>Hours : <input type="text" id='h' /></label>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE - Using a function. **

```
var hours = parseInt(prompt('Enter your hours please : '));

if (hours != null) {
  main();
}

function main(){
    document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
    alert(hours);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prince, but I am obligated to use my function `main ()` where I have to called my method main() ? I don't must to use the properties onload() because obsolete.

Comment: I have added a function that you can use to set the value of the input box.